# Remove words "Report Preview" in report title using QuickReport

Tags: delphi, report, delphi-10.4-sydney, quickreports

I use `QuickReport` to create the reports here. I would like to know if it is possible to remove the words 'Report Preview' in the title bar when previewing the report, beside of report title.

[image: Image example]

Comment: There are some sample applications showing how to modify the preview or use a custom preview form on the Quickreport website.  https://www.quickreport.co.uk/faqs/

Comment: @Brian doesn't work.